# Service worker update seems not detected

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

### Short Version

Looks like they are some inconsistent behaviour about service-worker mechanism. It could be due to the usage of the inspector chrome ? Don't know.

### Long version

I use service-worker in a single page application (aurelia framework). Everything works fine, but when my service-worker script change, on a remote server, the update is not detected. Looks like service-worker isn't requested (or may be ignored due to a kind of http cache ?).

In my development environment, I have no problem. If I change the content, the modification is detected and the service-worker update launched (they are no big differences between those two environment, http response headers are pretty the same).

**Some informations**

1. My service-worker is registered in my `index.html` :

```js
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
  navigator.serviceWorker.register(`${window.location.origin}/service-worker.js`).then((registration) => {
    console.info('SW - registered', registration);
  });
}
```

2. If I delete browser cache and reload, the service-worker is updated successfully (but I want it to be automatically done)
3. If I request my service-worker script through another browser, I can see a difference between both script. So I'm sure that the service worker installed script and the actual script version is different.
4. I already read some articles about service-worker, like : https://web.dev/service-worker-lifecycle/. I know `skipWaiting()`. But as I said, it works in my dev environment so, it can't be the problem (i'm anticipating some missreponse).

I am a bit confused. I think that the solution is the a difference between the remote server and the local server. But I could miss something about service-worker as that's not an easy subject.

---

**Edit** : To have more information, I used fiddler (a packet analyzer tool) to catch request to service-worker.js (because this browser call isn't display inside Chrome). The response is a 304 (not modified). It probably explain my problem.

**second edit** : I modified the service-worker.js on the remote server and the service worker was updated properly. Don't know why, but in one specific case, the service-worker.js is not updated and he's never updated (and get from cache in it's old version).

**third edit** : In my local environment, I had same kind of problem. The service-worker was not update. And ! This time, with fiddler, I found no 304 request about it. Like the service-worker was not requested at all. Tired of this. Looks like they are some inconsistent behaviour about service-worker mechanism. It could be due to the usage of the inspector chrome ? Don't know.

Comment: do you have a bit with `caches.open` - usually you put a version number in there so if you change the service worker, it will update

Comment: This shows how to remove old caches and only keep your new one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Cache

Comment: @Pete I have a VERSION variable with a timestamp that change with each version of the app. Both methods works I suppose (service worker change is detected with a byte to byte comparison). I will read your article. But I remove all cache when a new service worker is on 'activate' state

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the reason of my problem and why I chrome received a 304 from the server.

The response is inside HTTP headers [If-Modified-Since](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/If-Modified-Since) and [ETag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/ETag) : if one of these header changed, the content is returned and up to date. If-Modified-Since is the last date of modification and ETag is an hash who changed if the file changed.

In our case both of them failed.

#### If-Modified-Since

This date comes from the file system and change everytime your file is modified. But in our case, the application is an npm package. To dodge a bug, [npm set the explicitly the date to October 26 1985](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/20439).

In our build process, the package was unzipped, but the last modification was left intact. So the modified date in the header was always October 26 1985.

Ok and then ? Your etag can still do the job.
Here we go.

#### Etag

we use express.static to expose our client files, including service-worker.js.
When using express.static, you can only use weak etag. What is a weak etag ?
Weak etag from express use only two informations about the file :

- the last modification date : we see above that this date is always the same
- the length of the file : in our case we only change a timestamp as a version number, so the length is still the same

#### Conclusion

Our both headers If-Modified-Since and Etag did not changed. So... The cache was used everytime.